# Gstat krige() error: Covariance matrix singular at location [917300,3.6109e+06,0]: skipping

Tags: r, interpolation, spatial-statistics, kriging

Recently, I am facing a strange problem when using krige() in gstat library. This error was not there a few months ago because I am using the same code with the same data that I successfully used before. But now I am getting singular covariance matrix at grid points at which I want to krige the unknown values. I changed nothing in that old code. Just opened and ran, and now it would not run. Upon searching I found one solution set=list(cn_max = 1e10) from a communication between Edzer and Hengl under title "[R-sig-Geo] 'LDLfactor' error in 'krige' function". However, then krige() gives syntax error about cn_max. I also read "Error in In predict.gstat in R" question on this site, but it also does not work for me.

Why I am getting this error suddenly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the matrix library used by gstat. Historically (gstat was released as open source code in 1997) it used the LDLfactor routine in the meschach library. Around 6 months ago I factored this out this code and replaced it with the BLAS/LAPACK which are native in R. LAPACK uses Choleski decomposition. LDLfactor allows for some non-positive matrices, where Choleski will trigger an error on this.

So, your problem is apparently a non-positive definite matrix which was not detected by LDL, but was detected by Choleski.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So within the gstat is there any solution to overcome this issue? I tried setting list(cn_max = 1e10) but R does not recognize cn_max and gives syntax error.  I use the UTM coordinates.

Comment: Indeed, gstat does not solve this for you.

Comment: First attempt at using kriging here, and I'm also getting the "Covariance matrix singular" for all points.  Is there a solution, or are there other causes?

Comment: Addenda to my specific problem: I had duplicate input locations. In reference to the OP's problem, you can apparently set a variable "choleski" to 0 (zero) to reproduce the original behaviour. I haven't tried this.